# ¿porque mi modal aparece rapido y "desaparece"?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, bootstrap

Hola tengo un proyecto en ASP .NET con C# tengo un formulario para el cambio de contraseña, y para ello tengo un boton modificar en el cual al hacer click en el me debe mostrar un modal donde aparece un mensaje de que la contraseña ha sido modificada y un boton en donde debe dar click en aceptar y se debe cerrar la sesion. Este es mi codigo:

```
protected void btnModificar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Modificar();//funcion para modificar

//string para mostrar mi modal
            string modalScript = @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
             function openModal() {
                  $('#mymodal').modal('show');
                      }
            </script>";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "bsChgPwdModal", modalScript, false);//
        }
```

si me muestra el modal pero luego luego "desaparece" y yo quiero que se queda ahi para darle click al boton y me cierra la sesion. 
Gracias!!
Saludos

Comment: Hola, has probado hacerlo directamente desde javascript?

Comment: hacer el modal con javascript? pues no, no lo he intentado, porque la verdad no tengo idea de como, pero voy a intentarlo. Gracias

Comment: No hacerlo con javascript sino attacharte al evento click desde javascript y desde ahi hacer el modal('show') en vez de inyectar el javascript desde c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si usas bootstrap, hazlo directamente en Html y luego lo triggeas con el click y capturas datos al hacer close.

Te paso codigo de ejemplo.

Open Modal

```
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
   dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Link de ejemplo : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h